# iOS device not receiving PUSH notifications

Tags: ios, push-notification

The problem is this , the devices are not receiving the notifications sent from the server. However tested to send notifications via the APN Tester Free with the production certificate and devices so already receive notifications .

What could be happening?

Comment: http://apns-gcm.bryantan.info/ or 
http://pushmebaby.herokuapp.com you can check there your certificate and notification is correct or not

Comment: There are few possibilities a) Excessive payload. b) invalid token. c) Invalid certificate at server/backend. d) invalid configuration of bundle identifier/certificate on device. e) Permission issue on device. Check all of them you will get solution.

Comment: @DhavalBhadania. Pem File is the Apple push services certificate? I tried your first link and i have error 405 not allowed. Not excessive paylod, not invalid token, how i see it is a invalid certificate? how i see is invalid configuration os bundle? the user accept permission for received notification.

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/apn-tester-free/id626590577?mt=12 try this app you can test notification validation .

Comment: @DhavalBhadania, i tried this program, and the notification is send and received with no problems.
And because of that it is that I do not understand why it is not to give when the server sends

Comment: then problem with your backside developer check that proper way

Comment: @DhavalBhadania i debug my server side and the notifications is send, with no problems.

Comment: I use this code: NotificationPayload payload = new NotificationPayload(device,message);

List<NotificationPayload> payLoadsList = new List<NotificationPayload> { payload };PushNotification pushNotification = new PushNotification(false, path, password);
List<String> result = pushNotification.SendToApple(payLoadsList); the result is 0 instead 1 size.